# What folders and files from Laravel project are required to be deployed to the server?

Tags: laravel, apache, nginx, deployment, web-deployment

I have server, with Laravel project running on it. But that project contains only a fraction of files and folder from the original Laravel project (local version). Both (local and deployed) works fine.

Here is what i have on the server, as a deployed version:

```
(app)
(bootstrap)
(config)
(public)
(resources)
(storage)
(vendor)
.env
appspec.yml
artisan
```

And here is what i have locally, as a development version:

```
(.git)
(app)
(bootstrap)
(config)
(database)
(public)
(resources)
(storage)
(tests)
(vendor)
.env.example
.env
.gitattributes
.gitignore
artisan
composer.json
composer.lock
gulpfilejs
package.json
phpspec.yml
phpunit.xml
readme.md
zserver.php
```

For example, currently there is no "database" folder on the server. Deployed project requires no migrations, factories or seeds.

So, I wonder if there is a list of recommended or required folders and files of Laravel project, for it to be deployed?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to know what should, and what should not be on the server.

Answer (score -2):

In the project you have a file called .gitignore, in this file you will be told which folders or files you should skip when you upload to the server and more if you are using git obviously. I always ignore this:

```
/ node_modules
/ public / hot
/ public / storage
/storage/*.key
/ vendor
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
```

And I upload the .env file once with the configuration required by the server and then I also include it in the .gitignore, once uploaded to the server you will have to perform the commands of: composer update, php artisan migrate and all the necessary ones so that Your project works correctly on the server.

Comment: Well vendor still should be on the server, just not in git. Same for node_modules and your assets.